# unable to run my JavaFX project on IntelliJ IDEA with JDK-11

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-11

I am doing a project in IntelliJ IDEA on JavaFX application for the first time. I am unable to run my code.

When I first build->Run, I got an error saying that I require kotlin stdlib in my module,then I downloaded and added kotlin standard library into my module.
But now I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in my code .

Sample.Main

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

module-info.java file

```
module Calculator {

    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires kotlin.stdlib;

    opens Sample;
 }
```

fxml  file

```
<GridPane fx:controller="Sample.Controller"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
</GridPane>
```

error message:

```
 "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Coding_Setups\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52562:C:\Coding_Setups\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "G:\JavaFXproject\Calculator\out\production\Calculator;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Coding_Setups\javafx lib\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib\javafx-swt.jar" sample.Main

Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Sample/Main (wrong name: sample/Main)
```

I am confused why would my javafx project demand for kotlin stdlib and why I have added it to my module I am getting a new error even when I have not changed the provided code yet.

Comment: @Slaw your I followed your suggestion ,but it has not helped me
After changing vm options I was getting an error that module cannot
 find javafx.base, so I added that in my module-info.java file
 but still an error of not finding javafx.base is popping up.

Comment: You have posted `Sample.Main`, but there is no `package Sample;` in the source code. Later on, IntelliJ tries to use the main class `sample.Main`, and complains about a wrong name. Make sure you have the right package (it should be `sample`, following standard naming convention). It will help if you could directly test any of the samples [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ).